# What is better to use Exists or Select to set this value to bit variable?

Tags: sql, select, exists

I have bit(or int) variable which indicates if rows exists.

Yes, i know it will be better just to check with `EXISTS` but currently i need to set it value to my variable.

So question : what is better to use `SELECT` or `EXISTS`

```
DECLARE @signoff int    
set @signoff = 0


Set @signoff = (SELECT TOP 1
    AccountsOperations_ID
    FROM AccountsOperations
    WHERE Operation_ID = 3 and Submission_ID = @SubmissionID and AccountDate is null)
```

and then check

```
if @signoff is null or @signoff = 0
```

or

```
DECLARE @signoff bit
    set @signoff = 0

Set @signoff = SELECT CAST(
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1
             AccountsOperations_ID
             FROM AccountsOperations
             WHERE Operation_ID = 3 and Submission_ID = @SubmissionID and AccountDate is null) 
       THEN 1 
   ELSE 
        0 
   END 
AS BIT)
```

Comment: In the second example where are you setting the value to the variable? You are just setting 1 or 0 to it.

Comment: because `BIT` has only 2 possible values

Comment: I thought you wanted the value of AccountOperations_ID in your variable. The check what you are doing is not correct then. But if you just want your variable to be a flag then you should consider defaulting it to 0 and then IF EXISTS clause to set it to 1. That would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it would be this:

```
DECLARE @signoff bit
    set @signoff = 0

Set @signoff = SELECT CAST(
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM AccountsOperations
             WHERE Operation_ID = 3 and Submission_ID = @SubmissionID and AccountDate is null) 
       THEN 1 
   ELSE 
        0 
   END 
AS BIT)
```

You don't need the top at all, and it may cause extra work for the query.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the comment:

```
DECLARE @signoff bit
    set @signoff = 0

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM AccountsOperations
             WHERE Operation_ID = 3 and Submission_ID = @SubmissionID and AccountDate is null) 

SELECT @signoff = 1
```

You don't need the `TOP` or the `ELSE` as you are defaulting it to 0 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Using [IF EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188336.aspx) you can do that, it will return true if row exists else false.

```
    DECLARE @signoff bit


    IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
           AccountsOperations_ID
    FROM   AccountsOperations
    WHERE  Operation_ID = 3 and Submission_ID = @SubmissionID and AccountDate is null
    ) 
    SET signoff = 1 -- row exists
    ELSE
    SET signoff = 0 -- row doesn't exists
```